# How do you pass a Ref to a function in a <template> block

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a form that has a DateTime field. When the user changes the date, I want to first validate whether DateTime is valid before changing `tradeDateRef` (step 1). Then I want step 1 to trigger step 2's validation.

This is what I tried:

```
<script setup lang='ts'>
import * as v from 'vue'

let tradeDateRef = v.ref<DateTime>(DateTime.now())
let errs = {
  tradeDate: v.ref(''),
}

function onNewDate(it: DateTime, ref: v.Ref<DateTime>, err: v.Ref<string>) {
  // Step 1 validation that checks DateInput
  err.value = it.invalidExplanation ?? ''
  if (it.isValid)
    ref.value = it // <<< I want this to trigger step 2 validation
}

watchEffect(() => {
  // Step 2 validation that checks the entire form
  let tradeDate = tradeDateRef.value
}) 
</script>
<template>
<DateInput :modelValue="tradeDateRef"
           @update:modelValue="it => onNewDate(it, tradeDateRef, errs.tradeDate)" />
                                                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ compile error 
<div v-if="errs.tradeDate.value">{{errs.tradeDate.value}}</div>
</template>
```

However, I am unable to get `watchEffect()` to trigger after getting a valid DateInput. There is also a compiler error:

`Type '{ get: (unit: keyof DateTime) => number; readonly isValid: boolean; readonly invalidReason: string | null; readonly invalidExplanation: string | null; readonly locale: string; ... 67 more ...; toRelativeCalendar: (options?: ToRelativeCalendarOptions | undefined) => string | null; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Ref<DateTime>': value, [RefSymbol]`

I want to pass a `Ref` to `onNewDate` so that it triggers the `watchEffect()`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the issue by wrapping the `Ref`s in a POJsO, and referencing that in the `<template>` block instead.

```
<script>
let dateFields = {
  trade: {date:tradeDateRef,err: errs.tradeDate},
}

<template>
<DateInput :modelValue="tradeDateRef"
           @update:modelValue="it => onNewDate(it, dateFields.trade)" />
```